# ASP.NET Ajax actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

This code throws me an exception, what is wrong? It is supossed to open the modal after clicking on `Detail` link.

```
 <a href="@Ajax.ActionLink("Detail", "Skies", new {id = s.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", OnBegin = "openModalWindow" } )">Detail</a>
```

**Exception**

System.Web.HttpException: Z klienta (<) byla zjištěna potenciálně nebezpečná hodnota Request.Path.

Comment: You might start with sharing the exception details.

Comment: sorry, edited @Jasen

Comment: Also, you don't wrap `Ajax.ActionLink()` with an anchor tag `<a>`. The helper will create the html tag for you.

Comment: @Jasen That's It! Make an answer out of it, unwraping it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wrap `Ajax.ActionLink()` with an anchor tag `<a>`. The helper will create the html tag for you.